# is it possible to place test files in subfolder

Tags: go

When I have module and its test in the same directory it works ok.

```
- module1.go
- module1_test.go
```

But when number of files and test files grows it is hard to navigate through code.

Is it possible to place go tests to subfolder  for cleaner code structure? 
When I try to do it I got namespace error.

I placed file `module1_test.go` to folder `./test`

```
- module1.go
- test/module1_test.go
```

Now I got error on testing:

```
test/module1_test.go:8: undefined: someFunc
```

My `module1.go` code:

```
package package1

func someFunc() {

}
```

My `module1_test.go` code:

```
package package1

import (
    "testing"
)

func TestsomeFunc(t *testing.T) {
    someFunc()
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put the tests in another directory, but it is not common practice. Your tests will need to import the subject package and will not have access unexported methods in the subject package.  This will work:

File $GOPATH/src/somepath/package1/module1.go

```
package package1

func SomeFunc() {

}
```

File $GOPATH/src/somepath/package1/test/module1_test.go

```
package test

import (
    "testing"
    "somepath/package1"
)

func TestSomeFunc(t *testing.T) {
    package1.SomeFunc()
}
```

A couple of notes:

- I changed SomeFunc to an exported method so that the test can access it.
- The test imports the subject package "somepath/package1"